# Resizing an animation lags

Tags: android, performance, android-animation

I am developing an app and I wrote a code to resize the view as showing below

```
package com.lynx.zaindelivery.animations;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

/**
 * Created by moh.rababah on 5/5/2016.
 */
public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
    final int startWidth;
    final int targetHight;
    View view;

    public ResizeAnimation(View view, int targetHight) {
        this.view = view;
        this.targetHight = targetHight;
        startWidth = view.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        int newHight = (int) (startWidth + (targetHight - startWidth) * interpolatedTime);
        view.getLayoutParams().height = newHight;
            view.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It works fine but it's lagging(When the `targetHight` is high). Is there any way to improve the performance?